# Reading and Writing to a Named Pipe

Tags: c, named-pipes

I'm working with two programs. The **customer.c** program writes an int to a named pipe and the **bank.c** reads the pipe and prints the int. The customer will choose one of two named pipes, "atm1" and "atm2".

Ultimately I would like to run two customer.c programs, one for each pipe at the same time, but I have some issues with the writing and reading to the named pipe.

1. If I just run bank.c and one customer.c I don't get any output.
2. If I run bank.c and two customer.c the output doesn't always print or is out of order when it does.

I tried to use fsync() to flush but that didn't work either.

**customer.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd, num =0;
    if((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY)) == -1){
        ...
    }
    while(1){
        printf("Enter a integer:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num < 0){
            break;
        }
        if(write(fd, &num, sizeof(num)) <= 0){...}
        fsync(fd);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**bank.c**

```
int main(){
    int fd, sd, num=0, sret, fret, maxfd;
    //fd_set readfds;
    //struct timeval timeout;

    if(mkfifo("atm1", 0666) == -1){...}
    if(mkfifo("atm2", 0666) == -1){...}
    if((fd = open("atm1", O_RDONLY)) == -1){...}
    if((sd = open("atm2", O_RDONLY)) == -1){...}

    while(1){
        if((sret = read(sd, &num, sizeof(num))) > 0){
             printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        if((fret = read(fd, &num, sizeof(num))) > 0){
             printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        if(sret <= 0 && fret <= 0){
             break;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Any pointer?

Comment: 1. one customer, maybe bank.c blocks at read another customer's pipe; 2. don't always print, the reason same with #1; 3. not expected order, because your read order

Comment: Your bank program is blocked until there are two customers, one with the first named pipe open for writing and one (probably another) with the second named pipe open for writing.  Until both are open, the bank is blocked in the open calls.  As you'd find out if you ran the bank under a debugger, or added print statements after each open to report success.  You also read from `sd` (the second descriptor) before `fd` (the first descriptor) on each cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make multi-threads server for multiple same time recv. and require to check pipe name is already exist.

blank.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *client(void *data) 
{
    char *pname = (char*) data ;
    int sd =0 ;
    int num ;
    int sret=0 ;

    if((sd = open(pname, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("open failed:%s\n", pname) ;
        return NULL ;
    }
    printf("client[%d] start\n", sd) ;
    while(1){
        num=0 ;
        if((sret = read(sd, &num, sizeof(num))) > 0){
             printf("[%d] recv:%d\n", sd, num);
        }
        if(sret <= 0) {
             break;
        }
    }
    close(sd);
    printf("client[%d] end\n", sd) ;
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    int status ;
    pthread_t t1, t2 ;

    if(mkfifo("atm1", 0666) == -1) {
    printf("mkfifio failed : %d\n", errno) ;
    if (errno==EEXIST ) {
        printf("already exist. ignore\n") ;
    }
    else
        return -1;
    }
    if(mkfifo("atm2", 0666) == -1) {
    printf("mkfifio failed2 : %d\n", errno) ;
    if (errno==EEXIST ) {
        printf("already exist. ignore\n") ;
    }
    else
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, client, (void*)"atm1") ;
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, client, (void*)"atm2") ;

    pthread_join(t1, (void**)&status) ;
    pthread_join(t2, (void**)&status) ;

    return 0;
}
```

you can access the atm1 and atm2 at the same time.
./customer atm1
./customer atm2